# Getting sum of metrics for combinations of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this.

```
set language    group   version metric_1    metric_2    metric_3
X   English     1       A       100         20          5
X   French      2       A       90          10          10
X   English     1       B       80          30          15
X   French      2       B       70          20          20
Y   English     1       A       200         20          30
Y   French      2       A       180         30          20
Y   English     1       B       160         10          10
Y   French      2       B       140         20          5
```

I want to summarize the metrics with all the combinations of the experiment attributes - set, language, group & version. So the summary data frame will look like this.

```
set language    group   version metric_1    metric_2    metric_3
X                               800         140         80
Y                               1000        140         80
    English                     1200        200         80
    French                      600         80          80
                1               1050        120         60
                2               750         160         100
                        A       850         140         80
                        B       950         140         80
X   English                     500         100         40
X   French                      300         40          40
Y   English                     700         100         40
Y   French                      300         40          40
X               1               350         60          30
X               2               450         80          50
Y               1               700         60          30
Y               2               300         80          50
X                       A       350         70          40
X                       B       450         70          40
Y                       A       500         70          40
Y                       B       500         70          40
    English     1               ...
    English     2               ...
    French      1               ...
    French      2               ...
    English             A       ...
    English             B       ...
    French              A       ...
    French              B       ...
                1       A       ...
                1       B       ...
                2       A       ...
                2       B       ...
X   English     1               ...
X   English     2               ...
X   French      1               ...
X   French      2               ...
Y   English     1               ...
Y   English     2               ...
Y   French      1               ...
Y   French      2               ...
X   English             A       ...
X   English             B       ...
X   French              A       ...
X   French              B       ...
Y   English             A       ...
Y   English             B       ...
Y   French              A       ...
Y   French              B       ...
X               1       A       ...
X               1       B       ...
X               2       A       ...
X               2       B       ...
Y               1       A       ...
Y               1       B       ...
Y               2       A       ...
Y               2       B       ...
    English     1       A       ...
    English     1       B       ...
    English     2       A       ...
    English     2       B       ...
    French      1       A       ...
    French      1       B       ...
    French      2       A       ...
    French      2       B       ...
```

I know I can do this brute force with using the different combinations with groupby and concatenating all of those into a single data frame. This can potentially extend to many more attributes, so I'm trying to find a solution that is more scalable. I've been reading about functions available through itertools, but not sure how they would apply.

Appreciate any ideas / directions on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the function [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of `itertools` will help you to create all combinations you can. Let's suppose your data is in a dataframe called `df`.

```
from itertools import combinations
# create two list, one for all columns you want to sum, and the others
list_metric = [col for col in df.columns if 'metric' in col]
list_non_metric = [col for col in df.columns if 'metric' not in col]
# create the dataframe grouped on all columns
df_grouped = df.groupby(list_non_metric,as_index=False)[list_metric].sum() 
# use concat and list comprehension to create all the combinations
df_output = (pd.concat([df_grouped.groupby(list(combi),as_index=False)[list_metric].sum() 
                        for j in range(1, len(list_non_metric)+1) 
                          for combi in combinations(list_non_metric,j) ])
                 .fillna(''))
# reorder the columns as the input data (if necessary)
df_output = df_output[df.columns]
```

If you want to understand how works `combinations`, try to print these lines:

```
[combi for combi in combinations(list_non_metric,2)]
```

and then the second `for j in range(1, len(list_non_metric)+1)` will help to create the combinations of 1, 2, 3, ... elements of  `list_non_metric`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. I'm assuming you've only given a subset of your data because the totals don't add up:

```
In []:
import itertools as it

cols = df.columns.tolist()
index = ['set', 'language', 'group', 'version']
df = df.set_index(index)
pd.concat([df.groupby(level=x).sum().reset_index()
           for n in range(1, len(index)+1)
           for x in it.combinations(range(len(index)), n)],
          sort=True)[cols].fillna('')

Out[]:
   set language group version  metric_1  metric_2  metric_3
0    X                              340        80        50
1    Y                              680        80        65
0       English                     540        80        60
1        French                     480        80        55
0                   1               540        80        60
1                   2               480        80        55
0                           A       570        80        65
1                           B       450        80        50
0    X  English                     180        50        20
1    X   French                     160        30        30
2    Y  English                     360        30        40
3    Y   French                     320        50        25
...
```